# Find files/dirs the user have access to

Tags: permissions

I need to find the files and directories that a user **actually** have access to.

The user `admin1` is a member of the group `private`. The user `user1` is a member of the group `shared`. The current directory structure is given below:

```
drwxr-xr-x 29 root root      .
drwxr-x--- 2 root private    private-dir1/
-rw-r----- 1 root private      \_ private_file1
drwxr-x--- 2 root shared     shared-dir1/
-rw-r----- 1 root shared       \_ shared_file1
```

Now, the `user1` can see the dir `private-dir1/` and get `Permission denied` error when trying to `cd`.

My script uses commands like `ls, find, grep` etc to find the filenames to generate an interactive menu. My goal is to completely hide the files and dirs the user does not have access to.

Comment: Similar: [How to recursively check if a specfic user has read access to a folder and its contents?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/210093)

Comment: Or [Find files that a user can write, efficiently with minimal process creation](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/203628) for *write* access.

Comment: Also: [Find files that a user can not read?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/88573)